# Scope of promise function in protractor

Tags: protractor

This may be simple for you, but as a beginner it will be really helpful for me if I get a detailed answer.

In Protractor scripts, If I use a Promise while clicking on an object(For eg: a button), what are all the benefits? Whether It will wait only until the button object getting loaded or it will wait until all the objects inside the promise getting loaded?

Also I want to know that, is it an effective replacement for Sleep function in protractor script?
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default protractor wait is 11 seconds and further more you can customize waits in jasmine nodeopts in protractor configuration file

since we work on javascript, We may encounter promise issue because it is asynchronous,  before current tasks gets completed next task will be called, So script will throw an exception,  so we use Promise, callbacks

When the promise is fulfilled it will call resolve();

When the promise is not fulfilled it will call reject();

We can achieve this with next(), notify() and true conditions

Comment: Thanks for the reply Parthi. It will be really helpful if you can clarify whether giving wait time immediately after Promise is a good practice? or should we avoid wait time inside the promise function scope.

Comment: @Vishnu, you can avoid it by using Next() and notify() functions and if you think my above answer was useful please Upvote so that someone will get benefited.

Comment: Hi Parthi, 11 seconds wait time mentioning above is with the promise or without using the same? Also could you please provide an example snippet for using Next() and Notify().

Comment: @Vishnu,  11 Seconds wait time is without promise and here is the snippet,                                                                                                           
                                                                                                        
     Then(/^I click the "([^"]*)" button$/, function (arg, next) {
    if ('Create New' === arg) {
      pageObj.getCreateNewButton().click();
      next();
    }